# Inserting Site Catalyst in web sites -- Using XML only

Tags: xml, porting, adobe-analytics

In one website i need to insert SiteCatalyst tag by using XML. I cannot use JavaScript.

Could any one can help me?

BR,
Praji

Answer (score 2):

Adobe give the possibility to insert data through Data Insertion API.
Search it in the Adobe Analytics documentation.
You will have to call Analytics API sending all the data normally sent via query string parameter appenting them to the body af a POST call to Adobe Server.

Claudio.

Answer (score 0):

Use XSLT to transform the XML to XHTML with the embedded code as in this example:

```
<xsl:template name="sitecatalyst">
   <xsl:param name="query"/>
   <xsl:param name="matches"/>
   <xsl:comment>
     SiteCatalyst : Google Mini Search Integration
   </xsl:comment>
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="INSERT-DOMAIN-AND-PATH-TO-CODE/s_code.js"></script>
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
     <xsl:comment>
     s.eVar1="<xsl:value-of select='$query'/>"
     var s_code=s.t();if(s_code)document.write(s_code)
     </xsl:comment>
   </script>
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
     <xsl:comment>
     if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE')>=0)
        document.write("unescape('%3C')+'!-'+'-'")
    </xsl:comment>
  </script>
   <xsl:comment>
     End SiteCatalyst code version: H.16.
   </xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>
```

And place the following code in the opening `body` tag:

```
 <!-- *** Add Omniture SiteCatalyst code *** -->
 <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="RES">
     <xsl:call-template name="sitecatalyst">
       <xsl:with-param name="query" select="Q"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:call-template name="sitecatalyst">
       <xsl:with-param name="query" select="Q"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
```

To implement the HTTP requests server-side, a language with API support such as [frameworkless MXML](http://kb2.adobe.com/community/publishing/526/cpsid_52670.html) or a [non-XML language](https://github.com/chappy84/google-analytics-server-side) are required.

Comment: Thank you Paul.
I cannot use Javascripts any where in the site as i am developing the site for feature phone (Ketai). 
I implemented this with Omniture API.